# Kibana query language to java elasticsearch query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

Is there an easy way to get from a kibana query language string to a java elasticsearch query?

EDIT:
For example kibana query language string:
`foo:bar or test:123`

could be solved with java like

`BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(matchQuery("foo","bar")).minimumShouldMatch(1);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder2 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(matchQuery("test,"123")).minimumShouldMatch(1);
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder1 = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(List of queryBuilder1 and 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object of QueryBuider:

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("foo:bar or test:123");
```

After that just add it to the your SearchSourceBuilder:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
```

After add source to your SearchRequest and it should work fine:

```
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, there is:

1. Open Kibana and execute your KQL
2. Click on **Inspect** just above the query input field 
   [image]
3. In the slider appeared on the right side, click **Request**
   [image]
4. Find the "query" section in the shown JSON
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation of the kibana ui feature to look at the request against the elastic api. I think it is verys helpfull for people who dont know about. But my question is for the java query. So i need something that translate 
`cloud.maschine.type:"n1-standard-32"` to `QueryBuilders.boolQuery.should("n1-standard-32").minimumShouldMatch(1);`
Do you know what i mean?

Comment: Got your point. The High Level Rest Client is based on elastic Query-DLS and the KQL is just a kibana thing. I would try to translate the KQL to Query-DSL in the first step - I can´t find a java lib for this, but if you manage this, you'll have a Query-DSL JSON. In the next step use the XContent API to parse the JSON (see XContentParser, XContentFactory classes) and at the very end, use the SearchSourceBuilder classes to get your SearchQuery by the XContent. I'm curious what is the use case behind this question? Maybe there is another approach we can find?

Comment: Yes maybe we can find another approach, because the general overall question was, if i could integrate the Kibana UI searchbar into my application. Therefore i tried in the first step to translate the KQL to java. And then i would try to manage that autocompletion from the ui etc.  And yes i could try to reverse engineer the Kibana github project, but i thought that was a bit over the top.

Comment: doesn't really answer the question